# Can we still develop Silverlight 2 applications

Tags: silverlight

I've inherited a set of Silverlight 2 applications (new job), one of which needs upgrading. We can do the updates in code without problems, but the available dev machines all appear to be running Silverlight 3.

I can't seem to find Silverlight 2 tools for download any more - is there a way to multi-target Silverlight the same way we can multi-target older versions of the main CLR?

thanks

Toby

Answer (score 2):

There's really no reason to multitarget Silverlight. Unlike CLR, there isn't a side-by-side story: people run the latest version.

There's still an argument to develop for Silverlight 3, so go ahead and use the Silverlight 3 development tools - your Silverlight 2 apps should work just fine.

There may be some extremely limited, controlled environments without Internet or IT connectivity with Silverlight 2, but I'd expect that to be vary rare in my opinion. In such a case you could use MSBuild to build Silverlight 2 (even if you have newer bits on your machine) by placing the build tasks in your enlistment and redirecting from the standard SDK: http://www.jeff.wilcox.name/2009/03/sxs-sl2-sl3-building/

Here are the Silverlight 2 tools for Visual Studio 2008 SP1. You won't be able to developer Silverlight 2 apps in VS2010: http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?FamilyId=c22d6a7b-546f-4407-8ef6-d60c8ee221ed&displaylang=en

Comment: Hi Jeff,

the reason is that this is an internal company network, who haven't yet upgraded the plugins in their browsers

T

Comment: Fair enough, I'll see what else may be out there.

Comment: aha - found the SDK there too. Thanks - I'll remove the 3.0 tools from dev machine and give these a whirl, and let you know what happens

Comment: I uninstalled all the Silverlight 3 SDK and Tools items from the dev machine, rebooted and installed SL2 SDK & Tools. very helpfully, the VS Tools realised that there was a newer version of SL, and went and downloaded & installed 3.0!

I've heard a rumour of a physical machine that still has 2.0, it might be easier just to use that, though I'm scared that just thinking about it will cause it to auto-upgrade ...

Comment: Well you said this is an internal company network without Internet access. That's the environment in which you'll need to use these tools given that they are years old.